# Populate a portion of a cell based off another cells user input

Tags: excel, variables, formula, vlookup

Hello All wanted to start off by saying I appreciate your input and help. I'm not familiar with VB and so I am wondering if this can even be done in Excel. I have five columns that I would like populate based off a value entered off of another field. These are IP addresses, but the 2nd and 3rd octet will be variable. Each of the five columns will also have a different 4th octet but it is static to the column.

```
Example:

IP is 10.20.40.1 (This IP is Variable, each row would have a different value, so row 2 would be 10.20.41.1, and so forth.)

Column 1 = 10.20.40.0/28
Column 2 = 10.20.40.67/32
Column 3 = 10.20.40.65/32
Column 4 = 10.20.40.0/24
```

So the 4th octet of each column will always stay the same, what I would like the user to be able to do is enter in 10.20.40.1 into Column 0 which would then populate Column 1-4 with the IP's I need to have. I know I could do this by using 4 columns and then running a CONCENTATE but that would kind of defeat the purpose of the user inputting the raw data.

Is their a way to accomplish just with VLOOKUP? or Would I need to research VB and write something that could handle this?

Again thank you for taking the time to look at this!

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, I can use =SUBSTITUTE to replace the value and instead of trying to replace the 2nd or 3rd octect I can just convert the 4th octet using that formula.